# transition from Val to Val using Decaying Sine wave

Tags: javascript, css, math

I'm struggling to construct the formula which would allow me to transition from a start value, to a targeted end value while decaying over the specified time using a Sin or Cos wave?

I'm trying to mimic a bouncing effect as seen in my sample below using CSS and jsfiddle. I made this sample just for visuals. The final formula can be written in plain math, not language specific.

My goal is create a function which I can pass these core variables and have it return an array of all the positions.

```
start = 0.0 
end = 200.0 
duration = 1000 
bounces = 10
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerMartini/bkw8vqyc/3/

Comment: How is a starting value of `0.0` supposed to *decay* to an ending value of `200.0`? Perhaps you want a sinusoidal wave of decaying amplitude, but nothing in your problem description sheds any light on just how the amplitude is supposed to decay. In the final position the amplitude is presumably at least `200.00`, but beyond that nothing can be gleaned. It might help if you provide a sample graph of value vs. time showing what you have in mind. You can even freehand it.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with `animation-target` inside of `result`. Let's suppose you have an interval of **[a, b]** to animate. If we suppose that **P1** and **P2** are inside this interval and **|P1.x - P2.x| ~ 0**, but **|P1.x - P2.x| <> 0**, then you can calculate their **x** by their sine and cosine, respectively. If you think of the interval of [a, b] as of a successive set of points very close in each-other, then your global animation algorithm will look like this:

```
p1 <- a - step
p2 <- a
while p1 <= b
    p1 <- p2
    p2 <- p2 + step
    animate(p1, sin(p1), p2, sin(p2))
end while
```

Now, if you are working with Javascript, you will be able to do this by very close events, like `setInterval(yourfunction, 10);` If this is not smooth-enough, then you will be able to improve this with CSS styling for [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions), specifying the time it will take for each step, in this case, 10 milliseconds. You can use the `sin` and the `cos` functions of the [Math](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_math.asp) object in Javascript.